# How to obtain "correct" Roman Numerals in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I'm currently writing my second thesis template for LyX 2.0.6 under MiKTeX 2.9, and since I'm using the `article` document class I have to manually organize the page numbering inside the ToC, LoF, LoT et similia.

Thanks to `fancyhdr` I had no problems for the specific page number typesetting on the document body, which will be shown in the MWE; but when I began to organize my ToC formatting I encountered an issue that required this kind of help.

My goal is to obtain the Roman numbering for the pseudo-`frontmatter` inside the ToC without selecting `pagenumbering{Roman}`, because I want to use the Small Caps font selection.

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,british,italian]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\makeatletter
%
% define the page style, note \pagestyle{fancy} already in the preamble
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Sezione\ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% create new \fancypagestyles in respect to short sections
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{extramarks} 
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{nonTOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{TOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}
% 
% the pages of the ToC/LoF/LoT are numbered Lowercase Roman 
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagenumbering{roman}   % I don't want "Roman" because there are too big letters!
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \myTOC%
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Indice Generale}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}
\listoffigures
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Introduzione}
\lipsum[1]
%
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Prima sezione }
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Prima sottosezione }
\lipsum[3]
%
\end{document}
```

As it is complied, *the frontmatter pages have slanted small caps roman numerals*:

> [image]

but inside the ToC they appear *only lowercase upright roman*:

> [image]

My question so remains on *how to obtain the document body number style inside the ToC*, maybe using this imaginary command:

```
\newcommand*\ToCpagefont{\bfseries\scshape}  % roman-smallcaps-bold page number
```

Although I tried `tocloft` with the useful command:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecpagefont}{\uppercase\bfseries}
```

it gives me only undefined control sequences, and I think it is more reliable if every element inside the ToC formatting was adapted to this package; since I **don't use it** I'd like to know if there is some sort of solution to this starts-to-wear-me-off issue.

---

EDIT: Here is the MWE with addition of `Hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,british,italian]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage[unicode=true,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
%
\makeatletter
%
% define the page style, note \pagestyle{fancy} already in the preamble
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Sezione\ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% create new \fancypagestyles in respect to short sections
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{extramarks} 
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{nonTOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{TOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}
% 
% the pages of the ToC/LoF/LoT are numbered Lowercase Roman 
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagenumbering{roman}   % I don't want "Roman" because there are too big letters!
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \myTOC%
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Indice Generale}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}
\listoffigures
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Introduzione}
\lipsum[1]
%
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Prima sezione }
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Prima sottosezione }
\lipsum[3]
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to replace your `\addcontentsline` by `\addtocontents` more detailed macros. (in code comments: the more complicated case with package [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) loaded)

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,british,italian]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% \usepackage[unicode=true,
% bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
% breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
% {hyperref}
% %
% % see commented out lines below for this case with hyperref


\makeatletter
%
% define the page style, note \pagestyle{fancy} already in the preamble
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Sezione\ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% create new \fancypagestyles in respect to short sections
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{extramarks} 
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{nonTOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{TOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}
% 
% the pages of the ToC/LoF/LoT are numbered Lowercase Roman 
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagenumbering{roman}   % I don't want "Roman" because there are too big letters!
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \myTOC%
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\thispagestyle{plain}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Indice Generale}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Indice
    Generale}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}}

% in case hyperref is loaded use rather:
% \makeatletter
% \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Indice
%     Generale}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}{\@currentHref }}
% \makeatother

\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Elenco delle
    Figure}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}} 
% if hyperref:
% \makeatletter
% \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Elenco delle
%     Figure}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}{\@currentHref }} 
% \makeatother

\listoffigures
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Introduzione}
\lipsum[1]
%
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Prima sezione }
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Prima sottosezione }
\lipsum[3]
%
\end{document}
```

[image: page numbers in toc]

Comment: I think the lines suggested are to be used with `hyperref`, so I'll edit my question to add the `hyperref` requirements (by the way the code works great without the above mentioned package)

Comment: I have copied your `hyperref` loading to the code in my answer. What to do in that case with `hyperref` is indicated in the commented out parts of the code.

Answer (score 2):

After receiving the needed advices I came up with the final code edited only to create this particular macro that follows `hyperref` with the conditional `\@ifpackageloaded`:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
 \newcounter{forfunnysections}%
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}{\@currentHref}%
  }\stepcounter{forfunnysections}\pdfbookmark[1]{#3}{funny.\arabic{forfunnysections}}%
 }%
}{%
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}%
  }%
 }%  
}
```

In order to write someting similar to the previous command:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}  % old command
%
\addtoMYcontents{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}  % new command, with or without Hyperref
```

With this solution the preamble is not greatly altered and those sequences can be used easily to substitute the old command, giving now a more coherent typesetting inside the ToC.

Here is the final code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,british,italian]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
%
\makeatletter
% Newly defined command for Hyperref/Correct symbols
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
 \newcounter{forfunnysections}% 
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}{\@currentHref}%
  }\stepcounter{forfunnysections}\pdfbookmark[1]{#3}{funny.\arabic{forfunnysections}}%
 }%
}{%
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}%
  }%
 }%  
}
%
% define the page style, note \pagestyle{fancy} already in the preamble
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Sezione\ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%
% create new \fancypagestyles in respect to short sections
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{extramarks} 
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{nonTOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{TOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
} 
%  
% the pages of the ToC/LoF/LoT are numbered Lowercase Roman 
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagenumbering{roman}   % I don't want "Roman" because there are too big letters!
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \myTOC%
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addtoMYcontents{toc}{section}{Indice Generale}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\addtoMYcontents{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}
\listoffigures
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Introduzione}
\lipsum[1]
%
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Prima sezione }
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Prima sottosezione }
\lipsum[3]
%
\end{document}
```

The result given is as follows:

> [image]

Comment: one subtle point I passed under silence is that if you do a `pdf` and view the file in a viewer, the `bookmarks` will not have references to `Indice Generale`... this is because `hyperref` patches `\addcontentsline` but it does not patch `\addtocontents` and the patch does the thing for the bookmarks.

Comment: So to being able to connect the `bookmarks` neither `phantomsection` would work in this case. At this point is there any substitutible command to obtain the `Indice Generale` on the PDF `bookmarks`?

Comment: Yes, add to your macro in the `hyperref` case: `\pdfbookmark[1]{#3}{#3}`.

Comment: The code now works but could you please tell me if the edit I've done is now correct? I'm asking this because I don't know if there are more correct potitions to place this specific string.

Comment: You should move `\pdfbookmark[1]{#3}{#3}` after the closing brace of the `\addtocontents`. Besides  my suggestion is only if nothing fancy is in your section title: no `èà`... else the second `#3` should rather be something like `funny.\arabic{mycounter}` where `mycounter` is a LaTeX counter to be incremented by your macro. (I must check now...)

Comment: I thank you for your time, so after your deep thoughts let me see what will be the adaptive code for fancy section titles, I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: Ok, I checked if you wanted to use your macro with accented letters. The method would then be to have `\newcounter{forfunnysections}` and then inside `\addtoMYcontents`, after the closing brace of `\addtocontents`, `\stepcounter{forfunnysections}` followed with `\pdfbookmark[1]{#3}{funny.\arabic{forfunnysections}}`.

Comment: Ok, now I'll edit the code but please can you check if with the MWE it does work? Right now I have another issue with my PC and I can not have access to TeXworks, sorry...

Comment: yes it will work. Just move the `\newcounter` to the inside of the code conditional on `hyperref`, just before the definition of `\addtoMYcontents`.

Comment: rather than using `\@ifpackageloaded` I would do `\newif\ifwithhyperref`, then `\ifwithhyperref<all the stuff loading hyperref+the\addtoMycontents command>\else<the\addtoMycontents command>\fi`. Then you can at the top of your document have either `\withhyperreffalse` or `\withhyperreftrue`.

Comment: I'll add those lines (the fifth thank you is given `:-)` )

Comment: I give on purposes my advices step by step to get many thank you's ;-) besides, some real expert of `hyperref` might come by and have a better method!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\pagenumbering{Roman}` and correctly issue `\lowercase` in the headers:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,british,italian]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage[unicode=true,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
%
\makeatletter
%
% define the page style, note \pagestyle{fancy} already in the preamble
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Sezione\ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% create new \fancypagestyles in respect to short sections
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{extramarks} 
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{nonTOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{TOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape{\scshape \expandafter\lowercase\expandafter{\thepage}}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}
% 
% the pages of the ToC/LoF/LoT are numbered Lowercase Roman 
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagenumbering{Roman}   % I don't want "Roman" because there are too big letters!
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \myTOC%
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Indice Generale}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}
\listoffigures
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Introduzione}
\lipsum[1]
%
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Prima sezione }
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Prima sottosezione }
\lipsum[3]
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's an answer that gives not the Small Caps font for the page number inside the ToC, as my question was related to this transformation in the first place; but still `+1` for the time you spent thinking of a solution.

Comment: @tochecz looks as if your comment is in reply to the comment posted by AndreaL below my answer, not yours ?

Comment: @jfbu Damn, you're correct! I'll delete it.

Comment: @AndreaL. Well, in my opinion, the logical thing is that you want "Roman" just looking as "small-caps roman", which is what I do. Or when you refer to the page by `\pageref`, you want it to show `iii` instead of `III`?

Comment: This turned out just like you said, as I wrote my personal answer to [my next related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132086/latinmodern-is-messing-up-with-my-toc)