# LatinModern is messing up with my ToC

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, small-caps

Today I asked a question about [the ToC formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132014/how-to-obtain-correct-roman-numerals-in-toc) and I came up with a very unique macro that resolve all of my problems, but when I just began to enjoy the "answer" given another problem took me at the starting point: the adding of this line

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

*Takes the page numbers back into upright and not small caps.*

> [image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,british,italian]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{lmodern}  % inserting this line messes up evwrything but I'd like to use the same font.
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
%
\makeatletter
% Newly defined command for Hyperref/Correct symbols
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
 \newcounter{forfunnysections}% 
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}{\@currentHref}%
  }\stepcounter{forfunnysections}\pdfbookmark[1]{#3}{funny.\arabic{forfunnysections}}%
 }%
}{%
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\bfseries\scshape\thepage}}%
  }%
 }%  
}
%
% define the page style, note \pagestyle{fancy} already in the preamble
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Sezione\ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%
% create new \fancypagestyles in respect to short sections
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{extramarks} 
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{nonTOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{TOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape{\scshape \thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
} 
%  
% the pages of the ToC/LoF/LoT are numbered Lowercase Roman 
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagenumbering{roman}   % I don't want "Roman" because there are too big letters!
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \myTOC%
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addtoMYcontents{toc}{section}{Indice Generale}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\addtoMYcontents{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}
\listoffigures
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Introduzione}
\lipsum[1]
%
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Prima sezione }
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Prima sottosezione }
\lipsum[3]
%
\end{document}
```

The main question is that I do not know how a simple font could interact with the commands above, it's like the definition of SmallCaps that generates this issue but I'm not sure, so I wanted to know if *there exist a soliution that will keep me using `lmodern` but without the upright page numbers*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems Latin Modern does not provide for a bold variant of the small caps. So, try replacing

```
\bfseries\scshape
```

by

```
\usefont{T1}{cmr}{bx}{sc}
```

in your macro for the page number in the TOC. (compile twice after modifying your MWE as the toc file needs updating first).

Comment: Well, @jfbu you definetly deserve a coffee if I'll ever be able to meet you ;-). And this is the sixth thank you that you earned by me today.

Comment: I would need a coffee now as I have to pack my suitcase for a train trip tomorrow morning... ;-)

Comment: If a font family does provide boldface small caps, I throw it away. ;-) Except EC fonts, of course; anyway, actually using boldface small caps is a perversion.

Answer (score 1):

To put a definitive end to this issue, now the final code I wrote can be displayed; noticing that I could have added instead `\footnotesize\thepage` inside the macro and the definition of the fancy page styles by inserting `\pagenumbering{Roman}` in the first place; so the final code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,british,italian]{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage{lmodern}  % inserting this line messes up evwrything but I'd like to use the same font.
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
%
\makeatletter
% Newly defined command for Hyperref/Correct symbols
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
 \newcounter{forfunnysections}% 
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\footnotesize\thepage}}{\@currentHref}%
  }\stepcounter{forfunnysections}\pdfbookmark[1]{#3}{funny.\arabic{forfunnysections}}%
 }%
}{%
 \newcommand{\addtoMYcontents}[3]{% 
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
   \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{{\footnotesize\thepage}}%
  }%
 }%  
}
%
% define the page style, note \pagestyle{fancy} already in the preamble
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{Sezione\ \thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%
% create new \fancypagestyles in respect to short sections
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{extramarks} 
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\footnotesize{\slshape\thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{nonTOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{TOCplain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape \lastrightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\footnotesize{\slshape\thepage}}  % Page numbers with my defined style
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
} 
%  
% the pages of the ToC/LoF/LoT are numbered Lowercase Roman 
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagenumbering{Roman}
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \myTOC%
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addtoMYcontents{toc}{section}{Indice Generale}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\addtoMYcontents{toc}{section}{Elenco delle Figure}
\listoffigures
\clearpage{}
%
\thispagestyle{TOCplain}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Introduzione}
\lipsum[1]
%
\cleardoublepage{}
%
\thispagestyle{nonTOCplain}
\section{Prima sezione }
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Prima sottosezione }
\lipsum[3]
%
\end{document}
```

With this method the so called Bold Small Caps is no more considered (I hope that this behaviour would call me now a "reasonable" person and not a follower to this perversion according to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) `:-)`)